# Extreme Value (Gumbel) distribution a member of exponential family

Tags: distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics, exponential-family, gumbel-distribution

This is a question for discussion in my Linear Model class. I am having a hard time showing that the distribution belongs to the exponential family
PDF: $f(y; \theta) = 1/\varphi \exp([y − \theta]/\varphi − \exp[y − \theta]/\varphi)$.

I know it belongs to the exponential family, but I am finding it confusing showing it. Here is
the exponential form: pdf: $f(y; \theta) = s(y)t(\theta) \exp(a(y)b(\theta))$, where $s$, $y$, $a$, and $b$ are known functions.

If someone can help me approach the problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like there's a typo in your pdf of the Gumbel distribution: the second $\exp$ should be $\exp(-(y - \theta)/\varphi)$ instead of $\exp((y - \theta)/\varphi)$. Right now your function does not integrate to 1.

Comment: There's also a problem in your exponential family form: because you have two parameters, $\theta$ and $\varphi$, you need the exponential family form for a vector-valued parameter, so $a(y)$ and $b(\theta)$ are vectors and you should be using the dot product of them, i.e. $f(y; \theta, \varphi) = s(y)t(\theta, \varphi) \exp(a(y) \cdot b(\theta, \varphi))$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/372537/321264

Comment: You have to break the density into enough bits to recover the (three) defining elements of an exponential family, including the scalar product component $a(y)\cdot b(\theta,\varphi)$ in the exponential.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag,

Comment: Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/136339/7224